# Is it possible to loop over multiple objects and call to elements within each object in the loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

In R I would like to loop over a set of three functions, with the output requiring saving from each function with a name related to the input. This works when applied to one file but I would like to loop over 300+ objects and the function requires specifying elements within the object.

I attempted to create lists of the objects and output names and looping over it with a for loop for a single function (a.ppp) and received an error "Error in i[["X"]] : subscript out of bounds". I am very new to for loops and have limited coding background and am unsure if the loop structure i have created is correct. I have tried multiple options including looping over a dataframe or nesting loops based on some other stack overflow questions.

Some toy data, representing my setup. I have dataframes eg. a-g

```
a <- data.frame(X = c(1, 2, 3),
            Y = c(3,2,1),
            Z = c(4,5,6),
            M = c('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

I would like to loop over the following three functions.

```
library(spatstat)

a.ppp = ppp(a$X,a$Y,c(0,3),c(0,3),marks = a$M)
a.nnd = nndist(a.ppp,by=a.ppp$marks)
a.append = cbind(a,a.nnd)
```

My Attempt has included

```
listObj = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
list.ppp = c("a.ppp","b.ppp","c.ppp","d.ppp","e.ppp","f.ppp","g.ppp")

for (i in listObj) {
for (j in list.ppp) {

   j=ppp(i[["X"]],i[["Y"]],c(0,12),c(0,12),marks=i[["M"]])
  }
}
```

I recieved the error:

```
#Error in i[["X"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

My Expected results would be a .ppp and .append output for a to g

Just Thought I'd Follow up, Based on the extremely helpful comment from Joran. I have figured the issue out through a modification of his provided code. The code I used was as follows

```
library(spatstat)

 a <- data.frame(X = c(1, 2, 3),
                            Y = c(3,2,1),
                            Z = c(4,5,6),
                            M = c('A', 'B', 'C')) 

 #Create a list of all the vectors in the environment - Not an ideal method but 
 suitable for the case

 dfs= mget(ls())

 #Create empty lists to be populated during the loop
 dfs_ppp = list()
 dfs_nnd = list()
 dfs_final= list()


for (i in seq_along(dfs)){
 dfs_ppp[[i]] <- ppp(dfs[[i]]$X,dfs[[i]]$Y,c(-1,14),c(-1,14),marks = dfs[[i]]$M)
 dfs_nnd[[i]] = nndist(dfs_ppp[[i]],by=dfs_ppp[[i]]$marks)
 dfs_final[[i]] = cbind(dfs[[i]],dfs_nnd[[i]])  
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something more like this:

```
library(spatstat)

a <- data.frame(X = c(1, 2, 3),
                                Y = c(3,2,1),
                                Z = c(4,5,6),
                                M = c('A', 'B', 'C'))

# Put your data frames (a, b, c, etc.) in a list
dfs <- list(x = a,b = a,z = a)

for (i in seq_along(dfs)){
    ppp_obj <- ppp(dfs[[i]]$X,dfs[[i]]$Y,c(0,3),c(0,3),marks = dfs[[i]]$M)
    nnd_obj = nndist(ppp_obj,by=ppp_obj$marks)
    dfs[[i]]$nnd <- nnd_obj
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, the loop works great and based on a subset of the data it works. Is it possible to save each loop object? i.e. create a ppp_A, ppp_B, ppp_C ... and nnd_A, nnd_B, nnd_C where A,B,C is from i. As the loop in it's current form overwrites the data as it iterates through the DF. For Subsequent analyses I would need to loop through the nnd and ppp objects. Many thanks

Comment: A similar approach would be to use ```lapply()```. ```ppps <- lapply(dfs, function(DF) ppp(DF$X, ...)``` ```nnds <- lapply(ppps, function(ppp_obj) nndist(ppp_obj, ...)```. If you needed to append the list to the original ```dfs```, then you can do ```Map(data.frame, dfs, nnds)```.

Answer (score 0):

another approach, "functional style":

```
## two example dataframes a and b:
a <- b <- data.frame(X = c(1, 2, 3),
                     Y = c(3, 2, 1),
                     Z = c(4, 5, 6),
                     M = c('A', 'B', 'C')
                     )
```

- create helper function which returns a named list with 1. ppp and 2. original dataframe enriched with distance columns:

```
add_nnd <- function(d){
  the_ppp <-  with(d, ppp(X, Y, c(0,3), c(0,3), marks = M))
  the_appended <- cbind(d, nndist(the_ppp,
                                  by = as.factor(the_ppp$marks)
                                  ))
  list(the_ppp = the_ppp, the_appended = the_appended)
}
```

- get dataframes by name, apply helper and pick result item of choice:

```
## get the ppps:
list('a', 'b') |>  lapply(FUN = \(df_name) add_nnd(get(df_name))$the_ppp)
```

```
[[1]]
Marked planar point pattern: 3 points
marks are of storage type  'character'
window: rectangle = [0, 3] x [0, 3] units

[[2]]
Marked planar point pattern: 3 points
marks are of storage type  'character'
window: rectangle = [0, 3] x [0, 3] units
```

```
## geht the enriched dataframes:
list('a', 'b') |>  lapply(FUN = \(df_name) add_nnd(get(df_name))$the_appended)
```

```
[[1]]
  X Y Z M        A        B        C
1 1 3 4 A      Inf 1.414214 2.828427
2 2 2 5 B 1.414214      Inf 1.414214
3 3 1 6 C 2.828427 1.414214      Inf

[[2]]
  X Y Z M        A        B        C
1 1 3 4 A      Inf 1.414214 2.828427
2 2 2 5 B 1.414214      Inf 1.414214
3 3 1 6 C 2.828427 1.414214      Inf
```